# Moving objects to another object with delay

Tags: java, android, libgdx

In my 2D game I have the hero and coins that appear randomly. When the hero gets a power-up, his velocity increases so he flys faster.  Power-up is active for 10 seconds. When the powerup is active, if he is close to coins, coins should follow and collide with him like in Temple Run. I am not using any box2d type physics. For collision, I am using rectangular intersection checks and collision is not the problem here.

How do I achieve this effect of coins to follow the hero like magnets?

My current implementation is - check the distance between each coin in the coin group and the hero. If the target distance for coin movement is satisfied, change the coin's velocity on x based the on the velocity of the hero but this is not working as expected. How do I apply the impulse?

Comment: Change it based on the distance, not the velocity.

Comment: Thank you. I tried, this goes to startight to the Hero rather than like a magnet.

Comment: define "not working as expected"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to work on the inverse of the distance.  For reference, [Newton's (mostly correct) law of Universal Gravitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_law_of_universal_gravitation):

[image]

Where `F` is the force, `G` is some constant, `r` is the radius (the seperation distance), `m1` is the mass of the coin, and `m2` is the mass of the hero.

We also know [Newton's Second Law of Motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newtons_laws_of_motion):

[image]

Where `F` is the force, `m` is the mass of the coin, and `a` is the acceleration of the coin.

We can combine those two equasions to get:

[image]

From there, we know that the hero's "mass" is going to be proportional to the hero's area (2D objects don't really have mass but let's just pretend for a second), in other words:

[image]

Assuming you're scaling your hero equally in all directions, this means that the "mass" of your hero will be proportional to the square of the size scale factor `S`, like so:

[image]

This all boils down to:

[image]

Where `a` is the acceleration (the quantity you're looking for), `S` is the scale factor of the hero size, `d` is the distance from the hero to a coin, and `k` is a constant factor (just fudge it until coins move the right speed).

Comment: You sir is a rockstar! WIll try that but it makes so much sense.

Comment: I missed the inverse part in my comment.  oops.

Comment: @Wug I am in the same boat and need your help. What would be the value of the coin's x and y in every draw call until it collides with the hero? I tried putting the 'a' (the formula you gave above) on coin's x and hero's y as the y on coin's position. But it doesn't move rather just collides without movement.

Comment: `a` is the acceleration, the rate of change of the velocity.  velocity (`v`) is the rate of change of the position.  Every frame, add `a` to the velocity.